# Any idea about wireless ad hoc netwok management

Tags: networking, protocols, network-protocols

which protocols are used to manage the wireless ad hoc network? I know that ANMP is one of the protocol, but how it works and how it is different from SNMP. Plz help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANMP stands for Ad-hoc Network Management Protocol. ANMP is lightweight protocol which is compatible with SNMP, because SNMP is widely used management protocol. Ad hoc networks can be viewed as networks used to cover areas lacking a fixed infrastructure.

ANMP implementation details:
The PDU(Protocol Data Unit) structure is similar to SNMP’s PDU structure.

UDP is used for transmission of ANMP message.

Lost data is not retransmitted by ANMP, if node wishes to obtain lost information it can request to ANMP manager.